# Tools for documenting MVC web application

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture

I'm making a web application that is quite a bit more complicated than others I've produced in the past.  I think before I go much further I should try and get down a plan for the application as I currently have it.

I recently took a course in UML, but that doesn't seem particularly appropriate here - as while I'm using an object-oriented framework it is really the relationships between the Models, Controllers, Actions, Views and URL mappings I'm looking to document.

So my question is - **Are there any software design applications out there that are particularly useful for documenting the structure/functionality of an MVC application?**

On the basis of this I'd be hoping to write a testing plan.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is not for the creation of "testing plan" (whatever what means to you). If you want to test your application, you should have been writing unittests all along.

This sort of documentation is meant to alleviate the confusion in larges-scale applications. And the use of UML would be appropriate in this case, though there is no rule, that states you have to use all diagrams. But in your situation class or component diagram might be quite useful,  with some sequence diagrams to illustrate more confusing parts of the application.

Also some ER diagram might help, if you have a complicated DB structure.